# Map value to every value from set

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming

Let's say I have classes:

```
class SomeClass(
        val name: String
)

data class MyClass (
        val setValues: Set<SomeClass>,
        val intValue: Int
)
```

Then I create set like this:

```
val someClass1 = SomeClass("a")
val someClass2 = SomeClass("b")
val someClass3 = SomeClass("c")
val someClass4 = SomeClass("d")
val someClass5 = SomeClass("e")
val someClass6 = SomeClass("f")

val val1 = MyClass(setOf(someClass1, someClass2, someClass3), 1)
val val2 = MyClass(setOf(someClass1, someClass4, someClass5), 2)
val val3 = MyClass(setOf(someClass4, someClass5, someClass6), 3)

val setOfMyClass = setOf(val1, val2, val3)
```

and I want to do some operations on this set `setOfMyClass` like

`val result = set. ...`

and as a result get mapping like this:

```
someClass1 to 1
someClass2 to 1
someClass3 to 1
someClass1 to 2
someClass4 to 2
someClass5 to 2
someClass4 to 3
someClass5 to 3
someClass6 to 3
```

it probably should be some kind of list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `Set<MyClass>`, which each contains a `Set<SomeClass>`. To map a collection of collections into a single collection, usually `flatMap` is the solution. In your example, combining `flatMap` on the outer set and `map` on the inner set gives you a list of mapped pairs.

This gives you a `List<Pair<SomeClass, Int>>` - which is probably what you want?

```kotlin
val result = setOfMyClass.flatMap { myObject ->
    myObject.setValues.map { it to myObject.intValue }
}
```

Or if you want it as a `Map<SomeClass, Int>`, simply do the same as above and:

```kotlin
result.toMap()
```

Answer (score 0):

If i'm understand your question, the solution will be:
setValues.associateWith { intValue }
that will return Map<SomeClass, Int>

Comment: I start with a `Set<MyClass>` and I want to do it for all sets (setValues) from this main set.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question, but I'll give it a try.

Let's say *SomeClass* was Int and you want to compute *intValue + x* for every element *x* from *setValues*.

Int this case you'd do `myClassObject.setValues.map{Pair(it, myClassObject.intValue)}` and receive a list of the results. The result is a list and not a set, because some results could appear multiple times (as the mapping does not need to be injective), and the multiplicity of elements is lost in a set.